# Is there a better way to handle missing keys in Python?

Tags: python, json, key

I'm working with APIs that split out variable keys. Right now, I deal with this using a "try" but it looks super ugly, takes up four lines and I'm sure there must be a better way.

```
try:
    address = location['address']
except:
    address = ''
```

Comment: `location.get('address', '')`.

Comment: Also, don't use blanket exceptions. The exception thrown here is `KeyError`, so `except KeyError` would allow you to see memory errors, keyboard interrupts, generator exits and name errors still.

Comment: can you do nested gets? for example: 
    venue.get(location.get('address',''),'')

Comment: Sure you can, `dict.get()` is just a method call that returns an object, you can feed that object into another method call.